# codeigniter - APPPATH returns path after controller

Tags: codeigniter

I've got problems with sorting out the paths in my app.

I'm using APPPATH function to read/write my images's string path in my db. The problem is that the APPPATH puts the function after the controller

here is my function for getting the css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo '../' . APPPATH.'_data/css/style.css'; ?>" />
```

and when i go to `http://localhost/project/index.php/home` it works great
css links to `http://localhost/project/application/_data/css/style.css` which is correct

but then I have this other controller

```
http://localhost/project/index.php/member/index/1
```

The css file path has to be

```
href="<?php echo '../../../' . APPPATH."_data/css/style.css"; ?>"
```

because other wise my link to the css goes to

```
http://localhost/project/index.php/member/application/_data/css/style.css
```

I'm using a simple template structure where i have my header/content/footer in an include sub-folder in views and I'm sending data to the content. Pretty standard stuff. I just don't get why the APPPATH does not work as if when called it gives me the PATH to the APPLICATION folder regardless the class that's been used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`APPPATH` is really for system files, not frontend assets. It's the path to your application folder, and that's what it should be used for. `../relative/paths` rarely work well in Codeigniter since they are relative from the current URL (not the view file). This is really a mess you're getting into.

Simple solution is to use `base_url()` instead, but if you want shorter paths, this is what I use:

```
define('BASE_URI', str_replace('index.php', '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
```

In most cases, the result will be `/`, but this will account for CI installations in sub directories. For you, it should return `/project/`.

It's not recommended to keep static files like CSS and images mixed into your application files. Most people create a directory called `assets` or `public` to store them.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_URI.'public/css/style.css'; ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/css/style.css'; ?>" />
```

If you really need to store assets in your application folder, then just drop all the relative paths. You don't need them since `APPPATH` is absolute:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo APPPATH.'_data/css/style.css'; ?>" />
```

That should work from everywhere.

Comment: base_url() worked like a charm! Thanks for the advice. Will study the rest of the options too.

Comment: Another option: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#link_tag