# Codeigniter - APPATH points to Site/Router/application. Images not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I have a CodeIgniter page where the old developer has used the `APPPATH` instead of `base_url()`.

My application folder is like this: `domain/somefolder/CODEIGNITER INSTALLATION`.

Now, I recently had to code a new function on a router page - 
So the url goes `domain/somefolder/explore/hashtag/?tag=XXX`, now the images are not loading properly here. When looking, the inspector shows the path to be

```
domain/somefolder/explore/hashtag/application/view/uploads/image.jpg
```

etc. But on the *Explore page*, images are loaded fine, and inspector shows:

```
domain/somefolder/application/views/uploads/image.jpg
```

This is what I've been trying to do on the *Explore view* page:

```
if (isset($_GET['tag'])) 
{       
    $path = APPPATH . 'views/uploads/' . $username . '/profilePic_' .  '_0_150x';}
    $img_name = glob($path . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE); 
}
```

Where am I wrong?
Could somebody please help?

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411047/codeigniter-apppath-returns-path-after-controller

Comment: Already seen. The strange problem is when I use base_url() . '/application/views/uploads/' instead of APPPATH, I get the same URL as now I'm getting, but images show are null. 
The glob returns a null. I don't know why.
Please help.

Comment: Please check if $config['base_url'] is correctly set in application/config/config.php.

Comment: I've done the print_r(); on both, yes, it's correctly set.

Comment: If you have a htaccess folder in applications and if it says deny to all, then you will not be able to access images in application. Images should be in a main directory folder. If you need to access images make in application/.htaccess allow from all