# Handling file path change when uploaded on the web

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a working image uploading function in localhost.

However when I uploaded my site it tells me that the upload path does not appear to be valid. This is the complete error:

> /home/u937767376/public_html/public/resources/photos/pnpError creating
>   image.
>
> The upload path does not appear to be valid.

By the way I am using codeigniter as framework and this is my upload code:

```
public function img_normal_upload($id,$folder,$operation){

            $path = realpath(APPPATH . '../public/resources/photos/' . $folder );
            //var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\\ssmis\\public\\resources\\photos\\' . $folder . ' \\');
            echo $path;
            //checks if there is an image to be uploaded. If none, use default image.   
            if(!empty($_FILES) && $_FILES["userfile"]["name"] != "" && isset($_FILES["userfile"]["name"])){

                // Note we dont have to need $path be cause we do it already on $config
                $config = array (
                    'image_library' => 'gd',
                    'upload_path' =>  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\\ssmis\\public\\resources\\photos\\' . $folder . ' \\',
                    'file_name' =>  $id . '.jpg',
                    'allowed_types' => 'png|jpg|jpeg',
                    'overwrite' => TRUE,
                    'max_size' => '2000',   
                );
                $this->_CI->upload->initialize($config);
                //kapag failed
                if(!$this->_CI->upload->do_upload()){
                    echo 'Error creating image.';
                    echo $this->_CI->upload->display_errors();
                }else{
                    //now, the $path will become our resource path for copying and creating thumbnails.
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                if($operation === 'add'){
                    // Ang value ng APPPATH is application/ , this is not the root folder.
                    // Pwede ko siguro palitan ng $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] or dirname with str_replace
                    $resource_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../public/resources/default_picture.jpg');
                    //we have to append '/' kasi hindi niya nilalagay sa realpath ito
                    copy($resource_path, $path . '/' . $id . '.jpg');
                }                   
            }

            $this->_CI->image_lib->clear();
        }
```

The 'public/html' is where I uploaded all my files.
The '/home/u937767376' is the HOME ROOT as my web server is saying.

So what seems to be the error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try removing `public/` if that folder doesn't exist, seeing the error contains `public_html`

Comment: it exist sir, that's my folder sir.

Comment: I edited my question to explain what is public_html and /home/u937767376. TY

Comment: Can you confirm passed `$folder` is valid location?

Comment: i guess this will hep you 
check the APPPATH
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411047/codeigniter-apppath-returns-path-after-controller

Comment: Check CHMOD is 755 for that directory? Perhaps PHP is unable to write to that location.